# Stick-On Curtains or Stick-on Curtains

Tags: hyphens, capitalization

If the title of an article is about stick on curtains, should the title be "Stick-On Curtains" or "Stick-on Curtains"? In other words, should "o" in "stick-on" be capitalized?

Comment: Is that a brand of curtains or a type of curtain? I've never heard of them

Comment: For what it's worth, you could try this https://capitalizemytitle.com/

Comment: It's a type of curtains.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link! It's really useful!